# Missing value auth-url required for auth plugin password ERROR

Tags: authentication, openstack, pipenv

As i am trying to configurate openstack, when already in pipenv shell, i get this error

```
Missing value auth-url required for auth plugin password
```

when i call commands like : `openstack network list --external --column Name`.

It would be very helpful if someone could help me with this problem. I should add that before this, i already created a stack and VM using the Heat Orchestration, if that is important to the topic. I have spent a lot of time with this and by far nothing has worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you `source` the **adminrc.sh** file for `export` the environment parameters?

As the the error tips: `Missing value auth-url required for auth plugin password`, maybe you didn’t export the auth-url’s key-value parameter.

Check from this “[Create OpenStack client environment scripts](https://docs.openstack.org/liberty/install-guide-obs/keystone-openrc.html)”

Comment: @appleuser You are welcome, learn from each other.